# Не работает remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );

Tags: wordpress

Не работает remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );. Пытался даже закомментить add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); в defaul-filtres, не работает. Отступы в the_content остаются. Что делать?

Comment: Вопрос: а зачем? Что вы хотите получить?

Comment: Это хорошо, что не работает. Этого нельзя делать

Comment: убрать лишние отступы от the_content( убрать p).